# How can we store payload in database using wso2 API manager?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am publishing one custom API through rest HTTP endpoint and after publishing API I am subscribing the API. During subscription I am generating the production endpoint URL token and then trying to access the endpoint.I am able to get the api data on dashboard itself.

How can we store the corresponding api payload in database?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom sequence and use DB Report mediator within that. Following is a DBreport mediator sample config.

```
<dbreport description="">
            <connection>
               <pool>
                  <password>regadmin</password>
                  <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                  <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/regdb</url>
                  <user>regadmin</user>
               </pool>
            </connection>
            <statement>
               <sql>insert into tracker (`id`, `query`, `tracked`) values (NULL, ?, NOW())</sql>
               <parameter expression="get-property('uri.var.id')" type="VARCHAR"/>
            </statement>
         </dbreport>
```

You can read about adding custom sequences from [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Adding+Mediation+Extensions) and abount DBLookup mediator from [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/DBLookup+Mediator) and DBReport Mediator from [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/DB+Report+Mediator).